# MS Excel: Count the max spaces between a number frequency

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a column of numbers (i.e. 7,2,5,2,6,7,5,3,7,8,9,2,3,5,6,7)  What I am trying to do is count how many numbers are between each 7.  Not just the first, second, third, etc. but each instance.  So, in the number example at the beginning of this question, between the first 7 and the second 7 there are four numbers.  Between the second 7 and the third 7 there are two numbers.  Finally, between the fourth and fifth 7 there are 6 numbers.  In addition to counting the number of numbers between each 7, I would like to know what is the max numbers between 7s.  Is there a formula that will do this automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: Couldn't you just count the cells that *aren't* 7?

Answer (score 0):

1. find the row of the last 7 `B1=MATCH(7.5,A:A)`
2. count the number of 7's `B2=COUNTIF(A:A,7)`
3. Find all of the row numbers of the 7s

   1. `C1=MATCH(7,A:A,0)`
   2. `C2:C[B2]=MATCH(7,OFFSET($A$1,C1,0,$B$1-C1),0)+C1`*
4. Differences `D1:D[B2-1]=C2-C1-1`

Column D will now list the number of digits between adjacent 7's.

5. Maximum `=MAX(D:D)`